# filter double letter words from a list

Tags: python, list, filter

I have made a piece of code that filters a list, using a set of inputs from the user. Like wordle, if the letter is in the right place it is green, if it is in the wrong place you select yellow and if the letter is not in the word you select grey. however there is a small issue where if you have a word with two letter in it for example 'drill' and I say the first L is yellow but the second L is grey the code gets rid of all words with L, when I only want it to get rid of the double letter Ls.

```py
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        count = count + 1
        result = input('''what was the result of your letter? 
please write the colour
- green = g
- yellow = y
- grey = gr
answer: ''')
        if result.lower() == 'gr':
                letter11 = input('what is the letter: ')
                wlist = [word for word in wlist if not any(map(lambda x: x in word, letter11))]
        if result.lower() == 'g':
                letter12 = input('what was the letter: ')
                position11 = int(input('what was the position of the letter: '))
                wlist = [x for x in wlist if x[position11 - 1] == letter12]
        if result.lower() == 'y':
                letter13 = input('what was the letter: ')
                position13 = int(input('what was the position of the letter : '))
                wlist = [word for word in wlist if letter13 in word and word[position13-1] != letter13]
print(wlist,'choose any one of these words')
```

Comment: Given the way your code is set up, filtering letter by letter, I think it will be difficult to do what you want in a robust way as the order you enter the letters matters. It seems it would be better to re-factor your code to accept all the letter results first, then filter. To see this, think of the behaviro your code should take if you input 'drill' and the first 'l' is grey, and the second is yellow, is it the same behavior as if you order them in the opposite order?